# Optimization based on validation and not training

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, cnn, optimization

Hello neural network programmers,

I am currently creating a neural network with keras, as I am not that familiar with tensorflow and it's a bit more difficult.

I want my optimization to optimize the **validation** loss and **not** the training loss/accuracy.

Ideally, I would want it to look something like this:

> model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[**'val_accuray'**])

but val_accuracy is not something I can eneter into metrics.

Any ideas on how I can implement that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site! The optimization function in your model creation is not the best place to do what you want. What you should be doing is:

1. Create the model
2. Run as many epochs as you want during model training
3. During the epochs create Keras callbacks that save the best model based on validation accuracy (as opposed to other metrics)

That will allow you to still create your model in an efficient way while ending up with an epoch training process that creates the model with the highest validation accuracy.